# Python UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am trying to insert some data into a MySQL Database with this statment:

```
INSERT INTO tweets(tweeter,tweet)VALUES ('Lord_Sugar','RT @BTSport: This cerebral figure succeeds in insulting everyone’s intelligence. @CalvinBook looks at Kinnears impact on #NUFC http://t.…')
```

But I am getting this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 119: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I know which character its talking about - its '…' at the end of the tweet, but don't know how to get around it.

Comment: what does `print(repr('...'))` say the character consists of? the '...' being the odd characters.

Comment: That character isn't latin 1 sorry to say, it's something else so you need to decode it into erm 'iso-8859-15' or just run.

Comment: Python2 or Python3 btw? (makes a difference here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are connecting using MySQLDb.

If that is so, you should use charset and use_unicode parameters in your connection string. MySQLdb by default uses Latin-1:

```
import MySQLdb    
dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(user="root",db="twitter",use_unicode=True,charset='UTF8')
```